# How to start Strapi With MonogDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, devops, strapi

Everyone. I just started Strapi with MongoDB.
I followed the gudie on strapi.io but still failed.

Here is package.json

```
"dependencies": {
   "strapi": "3.0.0-beta.19.5",
   "strapi-admin": "3.0.0-beta.19.5",
   "strapi-utils": "3.0.0-beta.19.5",
   "strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "3.0.0-beta.19.5",
   "strapi-plugin-content-manager": "3.0.0-beta.19.5",
   "strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "3.0.0-beta.19.5",
   "strapi-plugin-email": "3.0.0-beta.19.5",
   "strapi-plugin-upload": "3.0.0-beta.19.5",
   "strapi-connector-mongoose": "3.0.0-beta.19.5"
},
```

This is development/database.json

```
{
 "defaultConnection": "default",
 "connections": {
 "default": {
   "connector": "mongoose",
   "settings": {
     "client": "mongo",
     "database": "nuclear-legacy",
     "host": "127.0.0.1",
     "srv": false,
     "port": 27017,
     "username": "",
     "password": ""
   },
   "options": {
     "authenticationDatabase": ""
   }
  }
 }
}
```

But sever doesn't start correctly, it restarts again and again infinitely.

> [2020-04-09T01:25:54.088Z] debug HEAD \admin (45 ms) 200
>
> [2020-04-09T01:25:54.094Z] info ⏳ Opening the admin panel...
>
> [2020-04-09T01:25:55.942Z] info File changed: F:\James\nuclear_program\backend\debug.log
>
> [2020-04-09T01:25:55.948Z] info The server is restarting

In mongodb compass, some collections have appeared in "nuclear-legacy" database.
But sever doesn't start correctly. I think the problem is that sever can't create admin user.

Very Stuck. I followed guide very carefully but can't figure out solution.

Also I want to know how to deploy React + Strapi project.
Strapi has own backend and frontend.
React is frontend for project.

Should I make two urls for frontend and backend?
Who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue myself.
It works after restart PC, Just some strange things.
However it works after restart.

I want to know how to deploy React + Strapi project.

Comment: If you're looking for help with React & Strapi, this should probably go in a separate, more specific question. That said, if you're just starting out I'd go through the tutorial they have created here: 
https://strapi.io/blog/build-a-blog-with-react-strapi-and-apollo

Comment: I already read that article. You comment is not fit for my question.